# How to pass dynamic column name to h2o arrange function

Tags: r, h2o

Given a `h2o` dataframe df with a numeric column col, the sort of df by col works if the column is defined specifically:

```
h2o.arrange(df, "col")
```

But the sort doesn't work when I passed a dynamic variable name:

```
var <- "A"
h2o.arrange(df, var)
```

I do not want to hard-coded the column name. Is there any way to solve it? Thanks.

#### added an example per Darren's request

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

df <- as.h2o(cars)

var <- "dist"

h2o.arrange(df, var) # got error

h2o.arrange(df, "dist") # works
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, e.g. using the iris data set. (I just tried, and even specifying the column directly does not appear to be doing anything; in addition the `desc` syntax shown at docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/sortcolumn.html gives me an error.

Comment: I just added the sample code. My H2O cluster version is 3.18.0.8. Thanks.

Comment: @JLi, I guess you mean the column: `displacement`. It doesn't work anyway. I tried with a simple data frame: `df <- as.h2o(data.frame (a=10:1, b = letters[1:10]))` and it does't work neither. for column `a`: `h2o.arrange(df.h2o, var)`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out to be quite tricky, but you can get the dynamic column name to be evaluated by using `call()`. So, to follow on from your example:

```
var <- "dist"
eval(call("h2o.arrange",df,var))
```

Gives:

```
  speed dist
1     4    2
2     7    4
3     4   10
4     9   10
```

Then:

```
var <- "speed"
eval(call("h2o.arrange",df,var))
```

Gives:

```
  speed dist
1     4    2
2     4   10
3     7    4
4     7   22
```

(I'd love to say that was the first thing I thought of, but it was more like experiment number 54! I was about halfway down http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html  There might be other, better ways, to achieve the same thing.)

By the way, another approach to achieve the same result is:

```
var = 1
h2o:::.newExpr("sort", df, var)
```

and

```
var = 0
h2o:::.newExpr("sort", df, var)
```

respectively. I.e. The 3rd argument is the zero-based index of the column. You can get *that* with `match(var, names(df)) - 1`. By this point you've implemented 75% of `h2o.arrange()`.

(Remember that any time you end up using `h2o:::` you are taking the risk that it will not work in some future version of H2O.)